# Born-like measuring rule in classical experiments

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, born-rule

this [2011 paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4269) "Born's rule from measurements of classical signals by threshold detectors which are properly calibrated" by Khrennikov investigates the theoretical possibility of [Born-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) measurement rule/ dynamics for classical systems but appears largely theoretical.

> are there any reported classical physics experiments/ measurements that exhibit Born-like measuring rules?

looking for papers etc., esp. in, but not limited to, acoustics.

Answer (score 4):

The oldest work on this preceeds quantum mechanics by more than 100 years. it was done by Malus in 1809 about experiments with polarized light. See http://arnold-neumaier.at/papers/physpapers.html#CQlightslides